# Postgres outputs nothing at all with select

Tags: postgresql

When running a select on a new table, postgres doesn't output anything

```
$ SELECT * FROM "my-schema"."my-table";
```

This is a new database and table, I expect to see at least the table formatted with headers etc.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had inadvertently disabled tuples (formatting) using

```
$ \t
Tuples only is on.
```

Running the command again and then the original command now shows a response

```
$ \t
Tuples only is off.

$ SELECT * FROM "my-schema"."my-table";
(0 rows)
```

As an aside, I should have tried the following;

```
$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "my-schema"."my-table";
```

Since there is always output regardless of the formatting

```
$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "my-schema"."my-table";
count | 0

$ \t
Tuples only is off.

$ SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "my-schema"."my-table";
-[ RECORD 1 ]
count | 0
```